# How to convert string with special control characters, like \'x1b', into a standard string?

Tags: python, sockets

When I use python socket program, we give an option like:

```
1) Input A to show your name
2) Input B to show your age
3) Input other to set your name

>>
```

When client types 'Too' + delete button + 'm', server receives 'Too\x1bm'.

How do I convert 'Too\x1bm' to 'Tom' in Python?

There may also be other control characters like 'move cursor' and 'tab'.

Comment: Is this Python2? I don't have the problem in neither Python2, nor Python3. I'm on a Mac.

Comment: What function are you using to capture the input? Using `input()`, or `raw_input()` on Python2, should handle backspaces, cursors keys, etc. just fine.

Comment: `\x1b` is the start of an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code -- you'd need to write a function to parse any of them that your client program can generate.

Comment: Socket programing, I can not use input or raw_input function. sock.send sock.recv only can be used

Comment: Show the code that generates this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the 'wrong characters' you can use .replace to remove unwanted parts.

```
'Too\x1bm'.replace(a[a.index('\x1b')-1:a.index('\x1b')+1],'')
returns >>> Tom
```

Comment: Server get 'Too\x1bm' not To\x1bm'

Comment: I've fixed it to remove '\x1b' and the character before it.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be:

```
line = 'Too\x1bm'

if '\x1b' in line:
    while True:
        index = line.find('\x1b')
        if index > 0:
            line = line[:index - 1] + line[index + 1:]
        else:
            break

    line = line.replace('\x1b', '')
```

Comment: Is there a library to do that?

Comment: Windows 'delete' is '\x1b'

Comment: Mac 'delete' is '\x7f'

Comment: I'm not aware of such library.